# for files Invalid argument/option - '>>'

Tags: batch-file

```
@ECHO OFF

Set LOG="C:\Temp\Copy.log"

::########################
:: Begin copying
::########################

Set Sourcedir="c:\data\PRODDB\dir"
Set Targetdir="C:\test"

Echo %date% %time%: "Copying from %sourcedir% to %Targetdir%" >> %LOG%

Forfiles /P "%Sourcedir%" /D +0 /C "cmd /c copy @path "%Targetdir%" >> %LOG%
```

when i execute the above script ,i am getting the below error                         ERROR: Invalid argument/option - '>>'.
Type "FORFILES /?" for usage.   what could be the issue here ? thanks

Answer (score 2):

the problem is on the /C parameter. You don't close your double quotes correctly.

try

```
Forfiles /P "%Sourcedir%" /D +0 /C "cmd /c copy @path %Targetdir%" >> %LOG%
```

Answer (score 2):

Both PA's answer and aphoria's answer will work in most cases. But they will fail if the `Targetdir` contains token delimiters like `<space>`, `=`, `;`, etc. or poison characters like `&`. Quotes are needed in such cases. Aphoria's answer looks like it might work, but the extra quotes cause `Targetdir` to not be quoted in the first parsing pass.

The solution is to use the FORFILES `0xNN` notation to represent the internal quotes.

```
Forfiles /P "%Sourcedir%" /D +0 /C "cmd /c copy @path 0x22%Targetdir%0x22" >> %LOG%
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a quote at the end of your command

Try this:

```
Forfiles /P "%Sourcedir%" /D +0 /C "cmd /c copy @path "%Targetdir%"" >> %LOG%
```

Note the `""` just before the `>>`.